# Struggling With Mod_Rewrite And Rewriting URL's

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I've been struggling all morning to try and work out how mod_rewrite works after reading countless tutorials.

I want to end up with links containing my page title and page id like the following.

```
http://www.example.com/$pageID/$page_title.html
```

Am I right in thinking I should run all links on my website through a php function that makes the link into the SEO'd link types like the above, then I'd get MOD_REWRITE in my .htaccess file to show content of the actual page I need?

Seems like a strange way of doing things? Is this normal? Do I need to disallow the unedited URL's from search engines to avoid dupe content issues?

Comment: To which url do you want to rewrite it?

Comment: what are the original links? (the ones you want them to end up as you described)

Comment: @micha www.mywebsite.com/category.php?id=97 is what it's like currently if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right in thinking I should run all links on my website through a php function that makes the link into the SEO'd link types like the above, then I'd get MOD_REWRITE in my .htaccess file to show content of the actual page I need?

This is one way to do it, it's based on an [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) model where everything goes through a controller. For example, if everything on your site is accessed through `/index.php` (e.g. http://yoursite.com/index.php?page_id=1234) then you just need to add some code to index.php to handle redirects if the requested URL includes `index.php`, then use mod_rewrite to rewrite SEO friendly URL's back to point to `/index.php`. If you already have a site and it doesn't do this, then you can either redesign or migrate it to a controller or try something else.

By something else, you *could* handle everything strictly with mod_rewrite by examining the request vs the URI. Say you have a page: http://www.evample.com/page.php?id=1234 you can employ these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /page.php\?id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1/ [R=301]
```

This makes requesting http://www.evample.com/page.php?id=1234 get a 301 redirect to http://www.evample.com/page/1234/

Now you need to write a rule to point it back to page.php, internally (note that this part is needed for the MVC solution as well):

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/$ /page.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This doesn't include the page's title in the redirect because mod_rewrite doesn't know anything about your site's page names. The page-title can be fetched if you were doing the redirect via page.php instead of using `%{THE_REQUEST}.

> Do I need to disallow the unedited URL's from search engines to avoid dupe content issues?

As long as you're redirecting using a 301, index bots will point to the new URL and resolve the duplicate.

Comment: I'm guessing the second method is best as all my links don't go through the same page, and to be honest I'd like to learn a bit more about mod_rewrite anyway. Which is the best way to fetch the page title then? How is that done? thanks

Comment: Fetching page title is not simple through mod_rewrite, it depends on where you have your titles stored (I assume in a database). You may be able to fetch by employing a RewriteMap and writing a script to fetch titles from the database.

Comment: Yes they're in a mySQL db. If i change my links to include the title like: `mywebsite.com/category.php?id=97&page_title=Page+Title` could i not use that to make the rewrite i want, or is this a bad way of doing things?

Comment: You could extract titles from a `page_title` query string param, but anyone can stick anything they want in there. Which means I can go to `mywebsite.com/category.php?id=97&page_title=made+up+title` and get redirected to `mywebsite.com/97/made+up+title` and that will cause duplicate content problems because it will be the same page as  `mywebsite.com/97/the+actual+title`

Comment: Which method would you advise out of the two suggested? I only have category.php, add_category.php, and add_post.php. so there aren't a lot of files if that makes any difference.

Comment: It would be easier to do a check at the top of those 3 php files and fetch the title from the database and redirect as opposed to creating a new script that does it and using a RewriteMap, IMO.

Comment: just to clarify, i'd do a 301 `header(location:)` script redirecting to the nicer looking title included URL. Then use mod_rewrite to show the correct page from that URL?

Comment: Correct, but you need to check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or something first to make sure you are not redirecting when the original request is the nicer looking URL, only when it is the category.php etc.